# Execute javascript on mongo command line with Authorization

Tags: javascript, mongodb, shell, command-line, authorization

I have been successfully executing javascripts from the mongo shell
We have now enabled authorization on the mongo database
The permissions have been given and if I login to the shell and execute queries everything is fine

However, I am trying to execute the javascript from command line and I have a problem

I am issuing the command
    mongo -u -p  -authenticationDatabase admin GetProcessDate.js

I get the error message

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.5
connecting to: test
2014-10-15T06:44:11.451-0700 error: { "$err" : "not authorized for query on bvmaster.ProcessDate", "code" : 13 } at src/mongo/shell/query.js:131
failed to load: GetProcessDate.js
```

When I disable authorization this javascript executes just fine

```
mongo GetProcessDate.js
```

When I enable authorization and login to the shell everything works fine

```
mongo -u <user>-p <password> -authenticationDatabase admin
```

The javascript is a very simple one

```
mongo = new Mongo();
bvmasternew = mongo.getDB( "bvmaster" );

ProcessDateCursor = bvmasternew.ProcessDate.find();
ProcessDateRec = ProcessDateCursor.next();
print( ProcessDateRec.Date);
```

Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searchs I found the following;
When you are executing a javascript on the mongo command line, it does not matter what parameters you pass on the command line
inside your mongo javascript
you need to call the mongo with proper parameters

```
mongo = new Mongo( server:port );
admin = mongo.getDB( "admin" );
admin.auth( User, Password );
```

These lines basically authorizes the user to perform various operations in that mongo instance you have connected using server/port combination